# Hibernate child tables are not updated

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3  mysql database tables called "Invoice","Selling","Invoice".ER diagram is as following. This is a simple database for billing application.

[image]

Invoice table keeps data about the invoice and Selling table keeps the items which are bought for the particular invoice. Item table keeps details about the each item.when the purchasing is done, the invoice is issued. This is how I save to database using Hibernate.Hsession is which my Sessionfactory is in and returns a session.`Date invoiceD = invoice.invoiceDate.getDate();` returns the invoice date successfully.

```
public boolean saveInvoice() {
    try {
        Session session = HSession.getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Date invoiceD = invoice.invoiceDate.getDate();
        Entity.Invoice inv = new Entity.Invoice();
        final int invcNo = this.invoiceNo;
        inv.setInvNo(invcNo);
        inv.setDateInv(invoiceD);
        inv.setValue(totalValue);
        inv.setInvDisc(discountAmount);
        inv.setInvNetvalue(netValue);
        inv.setInvPaid(paid);
        Set<Selling> sellings = new HashSet<Selling>();
        Iterator iterator = purchasingList.iterator();        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Item item = (Item) iterator.next();
            Selling sel = new Selling();
            SellingId sId = new SellingId();
            sId.setInvoiceInvNo(invcNo);
            sId.setItemItemid(item.getItemid());

            System.out.println("Selling .." + item.getItemid());

            sel.setId(sId);
            sel.setSellQty(item.getQty());
            sel.setSoldPrice(item.getSellingPrice());
            sel.setInvoice(inv);
            sel.setItem(item);
            sellings.add(sel);
        }
        inv.setSellings(sellings);

        session.save(inv);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }


}
```

**My problem is** only the invoice data saved but not selling details which are set to invoice `inv.setSellings(sellings);` (Invoice table has one to may relationship and all purchasing items objects are added to `Set` and then that set is added to invoice object.)
But when I save the Invoice and sellings *seperately* both are saved successfully.(saving invoice details in one session, comit its transaction, then again items are saved in another seperate session).(Hibernate mapping and creating entities were done with Netbeans IDE)

Please any one tell my where & what the problem is and where should I check. Also let me know how to see the hibernate sql execution in netbeans IDE.

Parent Invoice mapping;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 18, 2011 5:03:10 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entity.Invoice" table="invoice" catalog="ssm">
        <id name="invNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="inv_no" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="customer" class="Entity.Customer" fetch="select">
            <column name="Customer_cust_id" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="dateInv" type="date">
            <column name="date_inv" length="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="value" type="double">
            <column name="value" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="invDisc" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="inv_disc" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="invNetvalue" type="double">
            <column name="inv_netvalue" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="invPaid" type="double">
            <column name="inv_paid" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="cheqIncomes" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="Invoice_inv_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Entity.CheqIncome" />
        </set>
        <set name="sellings" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="Invoice_inv_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Entity.Selling" />
        </set>
        <set name="receipts" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="Invoice_inv_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Entity.Receipt" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

child entity; Selling

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 18, 2011 5:03:10 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entity.Selling" table="selling" catalog="ssm">
        <composite-id name="id" class="Entity.SellingId">
            <key-property name="invoiceInvNo" type="int">
                <column name="Invoice_inv_no" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="itemItemid" type="string">
                <column name="Item_itemid" length="12" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="invoice" class="Entity.Invoice" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="Invoice_inv_no" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="item" class="Entity.Item" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="Item_itemid" length="12" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="sellQty" type="int">
            <column name="sell_qty" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="soldPrice" type="double">
            <column name="sold_price" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: could you post mapping xml of parent and child tables ?

Comment: I added them into my question. Thank you for your attention

Comment: I think adding cascade="all" to the selling set will solve your problem. Please follow answer of Santosh and lets us know.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mak Ripon for your attention once again :) . The problem was in mapping.Now solved it with Santosh code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your mapping for Entity as pointed out by RichW above. Add cascade="all" to Set definition.

```
<set name="sellings" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="Invoice_inv_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Entity.Selling" />
        </set>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. The problem was there. problem solved

Answer (score 3):

In your Hibernate mapping for the Invoice entity you need to set the cascade type to "persist" or possibly to "all", depending on what you need. Refer to the Hibernate documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was there.